# JavaScript popup of table-calendar

Tags: javascript, html, calendar, html-table

In our school exercise we have to write our own calendar in Javascript. This I have accomplished and the calendar is ready as a `<table>`. Since it's a school exercise we cannot use ready made controls :-/

So the task could be described as: When I click on an `input` field the calendar should be shown next to the field - most likely below. How to make the table popup as some kind of overlay right next to the `input` field?

The only idea I have in mind is to use something like `document.getElementByID('myInput')` and than use `.innerHTML=calTable` but than the whole layout gets disoriented as soon as it shows up. And it's as well not an 'overlay'.

Any help or ideas?

Comment: Easiest way would probably to have an empty <div> ready and hidden where you want your calendar to appear, and to add a javascript click trigger that would add your calendar in there when you want.

Comment: agreed in sense to display it - most likely for the school exercise sufficient :-/ but using `div` would change as well the complete layout. Is there an _easy_ way to get it as some kind of overlay? something that lays over the other elements?